# Syntax Highlighting Plugins and 3.2.1

Tags: plugins

I was looking for some decent syntax highlighting plugins to display php code on posts. But most of the plugins in the wordpress repository are not updated for years. I found wp-syntax causing issues with the theme. So is there any good plugin with less bugs and better syntax highlighting that works fine with wordpress 3.2.1 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [SyntaxHighlighter Evolved](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/) on my site which is based on [Alex Gorbatchev’s SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) and used by [WordPress.com blogs/sites](http://en.support.wordpress.com/code/posting-source-code/) to get something like this:
[image]

And i just recently published a plugin named [Simple Gist Embed](http://en.bainternet.info/2011/simple-gist-embed)

> This Plugin allows to embed GitHub Gist to your posts/pages/custom
>   using a simple shortcode and even simpler using a built-in Tinymce
>   button. I know there are other plugins which do that already but this
>   plugin also lets you create a GitHub Gist From within your WordPress
>   admin. Other then the option to create Gists from your admin this
>   plugin is faster then the others because of it’s built-in caching of
>   Gists to the database.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using [CodeColorer](http://kpumuk.info/projects/wordpress-plugins/codecolorer/) on [my site](http://petermolnar.eu/sysadmin-blog/wordpress-3-0-network-with-nginx-and-php-fpm-backend-on-ubuntu-11-04-server/) (WP Network 3.2.1), and I'm OK with it this far. I tried a lot before and even this produces a not too beautiful HTML output, it works nice. I have to add I modified the CSS a bit from the original.